# Android - ActionBar - How to get color of hold event

Tags: android, android-actionbar

There's a way to know the color of hold event on action bar? Like image below:

The theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light

[image]

I just want the color value... but, how?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by using custom action bar.
Add in onCreate methode:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

// create xml in layout and inflate into view.

```
View v = getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.search, null);
```

// here you can find id add listener on add button.

```
Button addBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

addBtn.setonClickListener(this);
```

//Now add view in your action bar.

```
actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

I think it will help.

Comment: I was trying to get color values in my previous project but i could not get then solved by using this way.so i just explain may be it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This color is defined in xml file. you can create your own style by using:

[actionbar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

or you can see the source code of

[Theme.AppCompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml)

in summary this value is set statically and you can find it without needing to get it at the runtime because it is what you have styled.

for other part of your app you can create theme with

[android holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

**if you want the color value here it is:**

[The color is](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml#L171)

Comment: look at my answer again!